# Error in code while working towards creating ROC curve

Tags: r

I want to plot a ROC curve in R. I created a logistic Regg predictive model -modl4 already.
The code I executed towards creating the plot is:

```
train$predicted <- modl4$fitted.values
```

but this code is fetching error and the error says rows are mismatching. (Not able to copy actual error message from remote server).

2nd need is to have a single line of code to replace the NA values in a factor variable column with mode of that variable. IS THIS POSSIBLE?
(Please excuse my silly questions, I recently started working on R)

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you could provide a reproducible example of your code. You have probably assigned train model to a different vector and that's why the rows are mismatching.

You can replace `NA` with variables in one column. If I understand your question correctly, you have a column called `factor` in your data frame.

For the second question, you can find the mode with this function:

```
# Create the function.
getmode <- function(v) {
   uniqv <- unique(v)
   uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}
```

Then use the:

```
df$factor[df$factor=='NA'] <- getmode(df$factor)
```

This should work!

Comment: Thank you so much for the resonse.     train$predicted <- modl4$fitted.values. In this code, train is my data set, modl4 is the predictive model built on train data set.  I have same code written for another data set which we worked on in the class. it is working well.   In the case of second question.  Assume that I have a column in data frame (a fctor variable, its not numeric) handset_price which has several values including few NA values. I have to replace NA with mode of the variable handset_price .

Comment: Thanks! I can see that in your question. But, what is `train` assigned to prior to this line?

Comment: modl4<-glm( churn~., data = train_d, family = "binomial"). train has numeric as well as factor variables in it. It's a data frame

Comment: thank you so much for the code . How can i iterate it to replace multiple factor varibales.  I have check if the variable is 'factor' then replace NAs in that varible's values with mode of the respective variable